# Can't write to Socket when using an IP-Address

Tags: java, android, sockets, message

This is the code for my Server:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server().go();
}

public void go() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("Connection");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader br;
    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream is;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
        try {
            socket = clientSocket;
            is = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int k;
            while ((k = is.read()) != -1)
                System.out.print((char) k);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

And that is the Client:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Client().connect();
}

public void connect() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write("Hello World!".getBytes());
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Written");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Client-Side I connect to localhost and everything is working fine. But as soon as I replace "localhost" through my IP/DynDNS Address, the Server prints out "Connection", but the message is not received. But, when I add socket.close(), the message is sent. Why do I have to add socket.close() to send messages if I use my IP instead of "localhost"?
I think that this is also the reason why my android device can't connect to my Server. The Server prints out "Connection", but I can't write messages (just if I instantly close the socket afterwards or if I call socket.shutDownOutput().
I activaded port-forwarding on my router and on my firewall but now I run out of ideas... Why do I have a connection, but can't write?

EDIT: I don't have to close the Socket entirely, I juts have to close the PrintWriter. But why!?

Comment: How have you checked that the message is not received? `System.out.print(char)` may be accumulating output in a buffer...

Comment: If I am using "localhost" `System.out.print(char)` works... And what would be an other option to check if the message is received?

Comment: I was about to write an answer but than I saw, that your client code end immediatley after it writes one line to the socket. How can you say that the data is only sent, when the socket is explicitely closed?

Comment: If I use "localhost" the message is printed, and after that I of course get a SocketException. But when I use my IP, just NOTHING happens. "Connection" is printed but not the message and I don't get any Exception or so. But when I use my IP and add socket.close() or out.close() or socket.shutDownOutput(), everything is working (I just get the SocketException but the message is printed).